# How do I configure a USB modem to connect to the internet like you can do in linux?

Tags: windows, linux, usb, internet, modem

How can I configure windows to use a USB modem like I can do it on linux (http://forumz.in/1799-how-use-reliance-broadband-netconnect-ubuntu-linux/)

I need to bypass the std dialer software provided by the vendor, its exceptionally buggy/irksome and not easy to automate.

EDIT:

OS: Windows Vista (Home basic)
Modem: ZTE AC871 or may be AC8710

Comment: What version of Windows?  XP SP2, XP SP3, Vista, Vista SP1?

Comment: What kind of modem is it?  Based on the link, I assume you're using it for broadband of some kind.  What kind of broadband is it?

Comment: Yes I am using it for "always on" wireless broadband ( http://www.rcom.co.in/Communications/rcom/RNetconnect/netconnect_broadband_device.html )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find information on this hard to come by. As most people who want this level of control (i.e. not using the provided software) either get a "proper" router instead of a USB modem or are running Linux anyway, thre isn't much demand for the controls to exist.

One *very* hacky solution to try if you can not control the device the way you want under Windows is to see if it behaves well with Linux running in a VMWare (or similar) VM, set the VM to do NAT/masquerade for the host-only network, and have the Windows box use that VM as the default route.

Or if you have another machine lying around that you can use to run Linux on and have it run and share the modem link.

Both options are far from ideal (unless like me you have a small file/media/web server running Linux anyway, in which case the second option is practical), but might at least work until you get the Windows environment to let you configure the kit manually.